# p5.js Í How do I play first N frames as images in a loop?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, video-processing, p5.js

In the code below I want to:

1. save the first 5 seconds of the camera capture as frames
2. then each time round the `draw()` loop I want to draw the 1st frame on the canvas, then the 2nd one on the next draw loop, etc. until I reach the end and start back from the top.

However, this is not working and I believe it's because the `imageData` of each frame is an `data:image/octet-stream;base64,....` String which I'm not sure how to draw on the canvas.

```
const FRAME_RATE = 10
const CAPTURE_DURATION = 5 // secs

let framesCaptured = []
let i = 0

function setup() {
  frameRate(FRAME_RATE)
  
  let video = createCapture(VIDEO)
  
  video.hide()
  
  createCanvas(640, 480)
  
  saveFrames('frames', 'png', CAPTURE_DURATION, FRAME_RATE, (frames) => {
    framesCaptured = frames.map(({ imageData }) => {
      return imageData
    })
  })
}

function draw() {

  if (i < framesCaptured.length) {
    image(loadImage(framesCaptured[i]), 0, 0)
    i = i === framesCaptured.length - 1 ? 0 : i+1
  }
}
```

Btw, it's important that I have access to and loop through individual frame-images, because I will later be sending those to the server.

Answer (score 0):

LoadImage can handle base64 encoded images, but you have to add "data:image/png;base64," in front of the string.
you could try loadImage("data:image/png;base64,"+framesCaptured[i])

( https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadImage )

Comment: I've already tried this I'm afraid, thanks.

Comment: `framesCaptured[i]` already contains the `data:...` prefix, but it's `data:image/octet-stream;base64, ....`